# Python function to determine the right padding for an ESP Packet in IPsec

Tags: python

I have a project from school, where I should implement ESP Ipsec Encryption using python (really simple implementation) following a series of questions, in one of the question I should write a function to generate the necessary padding given the payload data length

Here is the question :

Write a function to return the appropriate padding given payload data length

padding can take on various values for its length. Typically, if a padding of length 2 (pad len = 2) achieves 4-byte alignment, then pad len = 2 + 4 also achieves such alignment. More generally, pad len = 2 + n * 4, where pad len < 255.

#code i've written

```
def pad(data_len):
    """ return the Padding field 
    Args:
        data_len: the length of the Data Payload 
    """
    # Determine the current length modulo 4
    current_mod = data_len % 4

    # Calculate the padding length needed for 4-byte alignment
    # It's the smallest number that, when added to current_mod, results in 4
    pad_len = (4 - current_mod) % 4

    # Generate the padding bytes
    padding_bytes = bytes(range(1, pad_len + 1))

    return padding_bytes
```

but after evaluation it fails to pass the test

```
 expected response: b'\x01'
  Evaluation b'\x01\x02\x03' versus the expected response (not revealed)
  - ERROR:   The object is not as expected. Your score is 0 / 1 points. Please see details below.
Tested Object: b'\x01\x02\x03'
```

Is there any other way to write the padding generator function ?

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is that the argument of the function should not be `data_len`, but `pad_len`. This does not make sense when reading your description, but does  probably fulfill the test requirement. The code would then become:

```
def pad(pad_len):

    # Generate the padding bytes
    padding_bytes = bytes(range(1, pad_len + 1))

    return padding_bytes
```